# F type female to SMA male adapter impedance question

Tags: connector, components, cables, impedance-matching, coax

I have a coaxial cable that I need to connect to a SMA female connect. The impedance of the cable is 75 ohms, and from online the SMA female connect is 50 ohms. Online there are a few places that sell F type female to SMA male adapters however most do not offer datasheets that specify the input/output impedance of the connector and if they do they only list the impedance without specifying.
 [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01FQE4BN6/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A26SKYU6EEPEEF&psc=1#customerReviews](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01FQE4BN6)

Comment: What frequencies are you working at? If the SMA cable length is sufficiently short with respect to your wavelength, and you use a 75 ohm termination resistance, it could be fine. The video industry used to use 50 Ohm BNC connectors for their 75 ohm lines because the little mismatch was insignificant at the frequencies they were working at, and the connectors were more commonly available.
SMA is always 50 Ohm, and F always 75 Ohm. A adapter would need a matching network in order to match, but I doubt the one you linked has such a network, given the price.

Comment: @JorenVaes I am working in 88-108MHz. Yea I figured since I found a few for 40ish.